# Absolute div within relative div with 100% page height

Tags: html, css

I have following html, which needs to remain as it is:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="content">some text</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Now I need to make the content div to fill the page in 100%. I tried following CSS with no luck:

```
body {
    height: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
    position: relative;    
}
#content {
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    height: 100%;
}
```

See here: http://www.cssdesk.com/hHZyD

Comment: Add `width:100%;height:100%` to both `#wrapper` and `#content`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/gLvr4gg3/)

I've edited the CSS as

**CSS**

```
html,body {
    height: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
    position: relative; 
    height: 100%;
}
#content {
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    height: 100%;
}
```

First of all, for height in percentage to work, height for `html` and `body should be set to 100%
ie

```
html,body {
        height: 100%;
}
```

Next for the percentage to work, the parent div should be given a height.So i've changed 
the css to

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative; 
    height: 100%;
}
```

**UPDATE**

As @ctwheels specified in his comment, if the OP needs both height and width to be 100%,

Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/gLvr4gg3/2/)

Here i have set width to 100% for both the divs.

Comment: what is happenning????why is the answer being continuously downvoted???it is the right one..The OP itself accepted it..

Comment: If the OP has accepted the answer, I will upvote, it was to my understanding that the OP was asking for content to fill the page (meaning both width and height). Your solution only attacked height, but not width. It seems it may have been a misunderstanding with what the OP was referring to when they said "Now I need to make the content div to fill the page in 100%"

Comment: Thank you. This covers both the OP's question (misunderstanding or not)

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/9qjonf6k/)**

css

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
}
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
#content {
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```